# VS Code Debugging for Node.js not working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

For some reason the VS Code debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints in recently created node.js projects. In some of my older projects it works like a charm. I use the same launch files but it wont work. The debugger starts and runs through but it doesn't stop on any breakpoints.

Someone had the same issue? I recognized this after the latest update but I can't find some forum entries describing my problem.

I'm running the VS Code Version 1.50.1 and Node.js Version 14.13.0.

This is the launch file of an older project which works:

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch LN Star",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\NL_Star\\main.js",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
```

This is the launch file of a new project which runs but doesn't stop on any breakpoint

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm glad to add some more information if needed and when I know how or where to look for it. But for now I don't really know where to start to fix this.

I guess I just missed something but I cant really find it!
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!